# Обновление значения

Tags: javascript

Есть масюсенький код, его я сделал с помошью другой темы и чуть подумав головой.

```
var a=(document.getElementsByName("products_qty")[0].value);
document.write(a);
```

В данную переменную записывается значение, введенное в поле инпут. И как бы мне хотелось (долго объяснять), что бы это же значение дублировалось в другом месте страницы. Т.е я меняю значение в поле инпут - меняется и значение переменной а.

Наверное, можно как-то оттолкнуться от того, что инпуты знают такую фишку как фокус. Т.е. мне кажется, что можно как-то заставлять меняться значение, как только я перестану вводить цифры.

Comment: onfocus на инпуте и на onkeyup выполнять анонимную функцию, которая будет присваивать значение инпута переменной **а** в тот момент, когда отжата любая клавиша! Погугилите, не ждите решения! Я бы написал скрипт, но, к сожалению, не в том настроении!

Comment: да не вопрос.
мнеб и надо было только отправные точки.
не люблю когда за меня кто то код пишет.
спасибо

Comment: Скобки не нужны.

Comment: Попробовал к инпуту прибавить

    onkeyup="thisqty()

и в html вставить

   function thisqty() {
       var a = document.getElementsByName("products_qty")[0].value;
       document.write(a);
   }

Как только введу что-то, то на белом поле появляется как раз вверенное мной значение, но страница пропадает. (((

Comment: Пропадание страницы уже недвусмысленно намекает, что пора прекращать попрошайничать сниппеты и приниматься за чтение мануалов.

Comment: страница пропадает потому что вы используете docement.write! создайте тестовый div и средством innerHTML отслеживайте результат! @karmadro4 +1

Comment: сделал так
<div id="text"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
a=document.getElementsByName("products_qty"); 
div=document.getElementById('text');
</script>
 <div id="buttonwindopen" onclick="div.innerHTML=a" >
    кнопка
</div>

у меня по умолчанию значение в инпуте value=1

и соответственно что бы я не ввле в инпут вылезает 1.
как отследить значение, которое я ввел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
 #fortextdiv{
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: #00FF00;
 }
</style>
<script>
function change(inpid,divid){
  var inpobj=document.getElementById(inpid);
  var divobj=document.getElementById(divid);
  divobj.innerHTML=inpobj.value;  
}
</script>
<div id="fortextdiv"></div>
<input type="text" id="fortextinput" onkeydown="change('fortextinput','fortextdiv')" value="">
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек!

Comment: @KoVaLsKy Примите ответ если он вас устраивает (нажав галочку рядом с ответом)

Comment: только заметил.
выводит предыдщее введенное значение.

т.е я сначала ввожу 1
ничего не выводится

вввожу 2
выводится 1

Comment: Можно заменить onKeyDown на onKeyUp

Comment: красота. Спасибо

Comment: а как к нему добавить, например .шт

я понимаю что можно просто дальше вставить шт в html но когда человек добаляет 1 товар, он ж не вводит количество, следовательно скрипт не срабатывает

Comment: @Rules нужно заменить)